# UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath doesn't scroll to the first row if it only has one item

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've implemented a tableView on the iPhone with the ability to search using the searchBar. I'm trying to mimic the effect that hides the searchBar in my tableView when it first loaded.

The behavior is expected when the tableView contains more than one row. However, it doesn't scroll to the first row when there is only one row. It shows the searchBar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                  animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't understand all the things (may be something wrong, when you add cells to the table - where is search bar, in what cell?)
but you can try

```
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, yValue, 10, 10) animated:YES];
```